# How can I compute the velocity vector of a vector field along a curve, considered as path in the tangent bundle?

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields, geodesic, tangent-bundle

Consider a Riemannian manifold $M$, a unit speed geodesic $\gamma\colon[0,l]\to M$ and a parallel unit vector field $E$ along $\gamma$. Let $f\colon [0,l]\to \mathbb{R}$ be some smooth function. Consider $t\mapsto f(t)E(t)$ as a path in $TM$.

Then the velocity vector $\dot{f(t)E(t)}$ should be $\dot{\gamma}(t)+f^{\prime}(t)E(t)$, but I don't understand the second term in this decomposition.

Does anyone know a formal proof of this?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please read this text about [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question).

Comment: I don't understand why you have the first term though. The "velocity vector" should be interpreted as $\nabla_{\dot \gamma} (fE)$, right?

Comment: But for the notion of a velocity vector I do not need the covariant derivative, right? I consider $TM$ as some manifold and $t\mapsto f(t)E(t)$ as some path in this manifold $TM$. Then I use the coordinates of the tangent bundle, this explains the first term. But I don't see the relation to the covariant derivative and how I can use the fact that $E$ is parallel and of length 1 to obtain the second term.

Comment: Okay.... I think I understand the notation now. You are thinking of $Y: I \to TM$, $Y(t) = f(t) E(t)$ and you ask for the velocity vector of this $Y$, correct?

Comment: Yes, this is what I meant. But I don't see how I obtain the second term.